# Basic Method for Targeting With Anchors In JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I can think of several ways to accomplish what I would like to do below using jQuery, but I would like to know of the most efficient way I can do so:

I have five visible boxes on my page. I have five hidden boxes on my page. Each visible box is "assigned" to a hidden box. When I click on a visible box, it will show the hidden box it is assigned to.

An example of the HTML I'm using is:

```
<div class="tag">Box 1</div>
<div class="tag">Box 2</div>
<div class="tag">Box 3</div>
<div class="tag">Box 4</div>
<div class="tag">Box 5</div>

<div class="hidden-tag">Box 1</div>
<div class="hidden-tag">Box 2</div>
<div class="hidden-tag">Box 3</div>
<div class="hidden-tag">Box 4</div>
<div class="hidden-tag">Box 5</div>
```

And then of course:

```
.hidden-tag {
    display: none;
}
```

**Using jQuery, what would be the most efficient way to show the hidden-tag Box 1 when I click on the tag Box 1?**

Keep in mind, I can edit the HTML if needed to draw a connection between each box and its partner.

Comment: you have to compare against the contents(text) of the divs.

Comment: For this example, the contents are the same. In my actual use case, though, the contents are different. I just made them the same here to draw the connection between the boxes. How would I do this with contents that are not in any way related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML (This is just a clear example. You could obviously use shorter words and no `-` as well)

```
<div id="tag1" class="tag">Box 1</div>
<div id="tag2" class="tag">Box 2</div>
<div id="tag3" class="tag">Box 3</div>
<div id="tag4" class="tag">Box 4</div>
<div id="tag5" class="tag">Box 5</div>

<div class="hidden hidden-tag1">Box 1</div>
<div class="hidden hidden-tag2">Box 2</div>
<div class="hidden hidden-tag3">Box 3</div>
<div class="hidden hidden-tag4">Box 4</div>
<div class="hidden hidden-tag5">Box 5</div>
```

jquery

```
$('.tag').on('click', function() {
    var x = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.hidden').hide();
    $('.hidden-' + x).show();
});
```

So with this jQuery, when you click on any .tag element, it will save that elements id as the variable `x`.

Then we hide all the .hidden's so that they disappear, but then show the one that we want.

Comment: This was exactly the sort of solution I was hoping to find. Thank you very much for this. That being said, what exactly is the purpose of `$('.hidden').hide();`? To hide any boxes that are already open?

Comment: @user3229383 Yes. So lets say a user clicks on box 4.. so its hidden box is now open, but then they click on box 2. If you didn't have the hide there then box 2 and 4 would now be open. Etc Etc.  So you hide them all first, and then just show the one they clicked for.

Comment: Working like a charm for me, I just had to make a minor adjustment. `$('hidden-' + x).show();` should actually be `$('.hidden-' + x).show();`. Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the method I would use.

```
var divsHidden$ = $('div.hidden-tag'), divs$;

divs$ = $('div.tag').on('click', function() {
   divsHidden$.toggle(false).eq(divs$.index(this)).toggle(true);
})
```